# Left/Right Rigged Foot Moving The Same Way

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, bones, weight-painting

I'm trying to rig my fox character, however, although the X mirror works fine (as demonstrated below), I cannot find a way to mirror in the Y axis.

https://gyazo.com/ede60dca0168eee3d3cdc52d9448cbd5

I want the legs to be able to be mirrored in the Y axis so that it's easier to create walk cycles etc. like the image displayed below.

[image: How I want the legs to mirror in the Y axis.]

Any way to fix this without redoing my entire rig?

Comment: Pose mode only has an X-mirror and bones can have suffixes for left and right (e.g. *pawn.L*) - but not for front and back. I don't think anything can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to mirror along the Y axis, as front bones have different orientations from back bones, so copying the animation values would lead to weird poses.